# Add background image to spring boot project

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I try to add a image as background image in a html file from a springboot project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <div th:replace="header :: myheader"></div>
    <style>
    body {
      background-image: url("Blue.png");
    }
    </style>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="row">
            <a th:href="@{/newDiab}" class="btn btn-primary my-2 btn-block">Inscription</a></br>
            <a th:href="@{/login}" class="btn btn-primary my-2 btn-block">Authentification</a></br>
            <a th:href="@{/help}" class="btn btn-primary my-2 btn-block">Help</a></br>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The weird thing is than when I run de page using the browser it use the following url I see it:
http://localhost:63342/MyTFE/templates/firstPage.html?_ijt=qobe818ectvkr4b3hb7kq4cnmk&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE
but when I run the entire project and using localhost with this url it's doesn't show:
http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a specific path for this purpose,  create an images folder and add a path something like this URL(../images/Blue.png). Also, use background image CSS position property (like mentioned below) so that you can check whether your image is appearing or not.

```
{
     background-image: url('w3css.gif');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-position: center; 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it didn't seem to solve the issue.
The image still doesn't show up when I use the localhost even if it's show when i just run it threw a browser without using localhost (wich mean the path working)